# Get time difference between am and pm using time span

Tags: c#

need to get time difference between 10 pm and 4 am. below is my code

```
 _firstShiftStartTime = new TimeSpan(_oOrgShiftDetailDTO.StartTime.Value.Hour,_oOrgShiftDetailDTO.StartTime.Value.Minute, _oOrgShiftDetailDTO.StartTime.Value.Second);
  
 _firstShiftEndTime = new TimeSpan(_ShiftDetailDTO.EndTime.Value.Hour, _ShiftDetailDTO.EndTime.Value.Minute, _ShiftDetailDTO.EndTime.Value.Second);
```

this returns two timespans 22.00.00 and 6.00.00. i need to get time difference between these two.

Comment: have you tried _subtracting them_?

Comment: Are you able to wait for .NET 6 to arrive with `TimeOnly` support? This specific scenario was discussed in the [anouncement blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/date-time-and-time-zone-enhancements-in-net-6/)

Comment: it did not work for me

Comment: Try NodaTime and then summon @JonSkeet

Comment: can you help with acode example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Stefano's Solution of using Subtract and then handling negative values

```
var difference = _firstShiftEndTime.Subtract(_firstShiftStartTime);

if (difference.Ticks < 0)
{
    difference = new TimeSpan(TimeSpan.TicksPerDay - difference.Negate().Ticks);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well i think you can do this

```
_firstShiftEndTime.Subtract(_firstShiftStartTime);
```

Like explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.subtract?view=net-5.0)

EDIT:
since you consider the negative values a not valid value I will do this

```
if (_firstShiftEndTime < _firstShiftStartTime)
                _firstShiftEndTime.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
    
var myResult =   _firstShiftEndTime.Subtract(_firstShiftStartTime);
```

Comment: This will give hours in negative... -16

Comment: no. this returns invalid value. i need to get difference from 10pm to 4 am

Comment: @Didu well than why use `TimeSpan` when seems you need `DateTime` ? Seems you need to take account of the day also

Comment: We can use the  above code and just modify  to handle negative values